# Azure Function occasionally still runs old code after deployment

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

Occasionally after deploying the latest bits to an azure function it still is running the older version of the function.  Here is the build of the .NET core azure function and deployment code.  Ideas for what is causing this.  No failures are seen in the deployment process and it only happens occasionally.  I've tried adding a restart step for the azure function to no avail.  As a temporary work around I am completely deleting the azure function and re-creating it in the build process but this is less than ideal.

// ARM for function

```
    {
  "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
  "name": "[variables('functionAppName')]",
  "location": "[parameters('location')]",
  "kind": "functionapp",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('hostingPlanName'))]",
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName'))]",
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccounts_calculationartifacts_name'))]"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('hostingPlanName'))]",
    "siteConfig": {
      "appSettings": [
        {
          "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
          "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('storageAccountName'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(variables('storageAccountid'),'2015-05-01-preview').key1)]"
        },
        {
            "name": "AzureWebJobsDashboard",
            "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('storageAccountName'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(variables('storageAccountid'),'2015-05-01-preview').key1)]"
        },
        {
          "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING",
          "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('storageAccountName'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(variables('storageAccountid'),'2015-05-01-preview').key1)]"
        },
        {
          "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE",
          "value": "[toLower(variables('functionAppName'))]"
        },
        {
          "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
          "value": "~3"
        },
        {
          "name": "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION",
          "value": "~10"
        },
        {
          "name": "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY",
          "value": "[reference(resourceId('microsoft.insights/components/', variables('applicationInsightsName')), '2015-05-01').InstrumentationKey]"
        },
        {
          "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
          "value": "[variables('functionWorkerRuntime')]"
        },
        {
          "name": "WEBSITE_ENABLE_SYNC_UPDATE_SITE",
          "value": "true",
          "slotSetting": false
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

// yaml build step

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Build
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: |
      **/$(myProject).csproj
    arguments: --output $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output --configuration Release
```

// yaml deploy step

```
      - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
        displayName: 'Azure functions app deploy'
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
          appType: functionApp
          appName: $(myAppName)
          package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
```

Comment: I just had another interesting thing happen.  This time even after deleting and redeploying the azure function it didn't seem to deploy the function or host it correctly despite showing it as successful in the yaml pipeline.

Comment: Extract from deployment log..Trying to update App Service Application settings. Data: {"WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE":"1"}
Deleting App Service Application settings. Data: ["WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_ZIP"]
Updated App Service Application settings and Kudu Application settings.
Package deployment using ZIP Deploy initiated.
Successfully deployed web package to App Service.
NOTE: Run From Package makes wwwroot read-only, so you will receive an error when writing files to this directory.
Successfully updated App Service configuration details

Answer (score 1):

It could be that your functions are long running. A call to the function will run the version of the code that was available when the function was called.

Scenario 1:

- T0: Call comes in and V1 of the function starts running
- T1: V2 of the function is deployed
- T2: Call completes using V1 of the function

Scenario 2:

- T0: V1 of the function is running
- T1: Deployment of V2 starts
- T2: Call comes in, since deployment of V2 is not complete V1 responds

If the function is still responding with V1 several minutes after the deploy, then something else is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the response...yeah, it is responding for several hours with the wrong function so that isn't it.

Comment: If V1 and V2 of a function are both running, do you know if they are executing in entirely separate processes? E.g. is it possible for both versions to access a global or shared variable? Something like this would mean i can terminate a background thread from an old version that seems to keep running.

Comment: In answer to my own question, Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable and Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable works. Two versions of the function can reach the same shared variables here; so they must be running in the same process.